# merging two collections time stamped data and showing real time result

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework, real-time, minimongo

**The `Inocmes` and `Expenses` collections used complete separately in many places in whole app. there is only one page which have the below requirement. I don't believe there is no workaround in Mongodb, which really have millions of users :(**

I am using React-Meteor in a project have two collection named `Incomes` and `Expenses`. income Doc look like below

```
{
    "_id" : "euAeJYArsAyFWLJs6",
    "account" : "3m5Zxsije9b6ZaNpu",
    "amount" : 3,
    "receivedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-07T06:21:00.000Z"),
    "type" : "project",
    "project" : {
        "_id" : "ec2WLt3GzHNwhK7oK",
        "name" : "test"
    },
    "owner" : "nM4ToQEbYBsC3NoQB",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-07-07T06:21:37.293Z")
}
```

and below how the expense Doc look like

```
{
    "_id" : "snWDusDbkLHHY2Yry",
    "account" : "3m5Zxsije9b6ZaNpu",
    "amount" : 4,
    "spentAt" : ISODate("2017-07-07T06:21:00.000Z"),
    "description" : "4",
    "category" : {
        "_id" : "vh593tw9dZgNdNwtr",
        "name" : "test",
        "icon" : "icon-icons_tution-fee"
    },
    "owner" : "nM4ToQEbYBsC3NoQB",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-07-07T06:22:04.215Z")
}
```

Now I have a page called transactions where I have to show all transaction (incomes and expenses) based on Time so my publication code for transactions look like below

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Incomes } from '../../incomes/incomes.js';
import { Expenses } from '../../expences/expenses.js';
import { Counter } from 'meteor/natestrauser:publish-performant-counts';


let datefilter = (options, query) => {
    let dateQuery = {$gte: new Date(options.dateFilter.start), $lte: new Date(options.dateFilter.end)};
    let temp = {$or: [{receivedAt: dateQuery}, {spentAt: dateQuery}]};
    query.$and.push(temp);
};
Meteor.publish('transactions', function(options) {
    let query = {
        owner: this.userId,
        $and: []
    };

    if(options.accounts.length)
        query['account'] = {$in: options.accounts};

    options.dateFilter && datefilter(options, query);
    //here i also apply other filter based on category and project which does not matter so i removed

    if(!query.$and.length) delete query.$and;

    //computing 'Transactions' below
    return [
        Incomes.find(query, {
            sort: {
                receivedAt: -1
            },
            limit: options.limit,
            skip: options.skip
        }),
        Expenses.find(query, {
            sort: {
                spentAt: -1
            },
            limit: options.limit,
            skip: options.skip
        })
    ]
});
```

Till here every thing working fine until I have to implement pagination on transaction page, so here data have to be sorted by Date. that's the real problem. Assume my both collections have 10 record each and my Template page have to contain first 10 result, so I sent skip 0 and limit 10, in return I got 10 incomes and 10 expenses records and on second page there is no record because skip and limit sent 10 for both. so how to deal with it? I also used counter Technic but that didn't work. remember my data is real time too.
any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You could simply and actually solve your problem by simply "merging" the collections in the first place. If I were you I would do exactly that, and instead simply add a "type" for "Income" and one for "Expense" to the items in each collection and merge them. Outside of that, what you are asking for is like a SQL UNION query with sorting and paging over the "union" of results. There is actually no MongoDB operation that directly correlates to this. Which leaves actually merging the collections at their source as the most sane option,

Comment: please explain the "merging" term, using map reduce || aggregate or just removed two collection and make single collection entirely?

Comment: Let me be clearer. MongoDB has NO METHOD for merging the data from two sources for query in the way you want. You NEED to actually create a "new collection" combining both of your collections. So yes.Remove the two and make a single. Then there is no problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thx, could you also suggest best approach for this please

Comment: Loop the data with `.bulkWrite()`. You may get away with using `$out` with `.aggregate()` for one of the collections, but you cannot "append" the second. Various examples at [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a Temporary Solution for a quick join Issue, You should
>   consider your data-set amount and passed all checks before apply Meantime I will change my schema as @NeilLunn suggested and plan migrations shortly.

For the adhoc Fix that meet the display requirements I applied the `aggregate` with the combination of `$out`. Now the code look like below

```
Meteor.publish('transaction', function(options){
    //here I perform many filter based on query and options
    //which deleted to shorten code on SO

    //call asynchronous method just to get result delay :)
    Meteor.call('copyTransactions', (err, res) => {
        //something do here
    });
    //note the we return results from **Transactions** which is comes as third collection
    return [
        Transactions.find(query, {
            sort: sortbyDate,
            skip: options.skip,
            limit: options.limit,
        }),
        new Counter('transactionsCount', Transactions.find(query, {
            sort: sortbyDate
        }))
    ];
});
```

Now publish **Transactions** (a separate collection) which I desired as a merge collection . Note this one ends with `s` in name as `transactions` so don't confuse with above one (`transaction`)

> publish the merge collection separately as "transactions"

```
Meteor.publish('transactions', function(limit){
    return Transactions.find(
        {
            owner: this.userId
        });
});
```

and here is the most important method which called in publication to merge  two collection in third collection in which I first `aggregated` all result with `$out` and then append second collection with [batch](https://atmospherejs.com/mikowals/batch-insert) insert

```
import { Expenses } from '../../../api/expences/expenses'
import { Incomes } from '../../../api/incomes/incomes'
import { Transactions } from '../transactions'
import Future from 'fibers/future';
export const copyTransactions = new ValidatedMethod({
    name: 'copyTransactions',
    validate:null,
    run() {
        //we are using future here to make it asynchronous
        let fu = new Future();
        //here Expenses directly copied in new collection name Transactions
        // TODO: use $rename or $addField in aggregate instead of $project
        Expenses.aggregate([{
            $project: {
                account : "$account",
                amount : "$amount",
                transactionAt : "$spentAt",
                description : "$description",
                category : "$category",
                type: {
                    $literal: 'expense'
                },
                owner : "$owner",
                createdAt : "$createdAt"
            }
        }, {
            $out: "transactions"
        } ]);
        //now append Transactions collection with incomes with batch insert
        Incomes.aggregate([{
            $project: {
                account : "$account",
                amount : "$amount",
                transactionAt : "$receivedAt",
                type:{
                    $literal: 'income'
                },
                project : "$project",
                owner : "$owner",
                createdAt : "$createdAt"
            }
        }], function (err, result) {
            //if no doc found then just return
            if(!result.length){
                fu.return('completed')
            }
            else{
                Transactions.batchInsert(result, function(err, res){
                    fu.return('completed')
                })
            }

        });
        return fu.wait();
    }
});
```

> If Second Collection `aggregated` too with `$out` then it will
>   overwrite :(

@client I just have to subscribe the 'transaction' with my options and query and got the real time merge results from `Transactions`

Comment: I used `$project` because my current version not supported `$rename` and `$addField` unfortunately